# Any way to force Android to treat copied pasted images as new?

Tags: gallery, images, art

I have some art apps that only let you choose images from built-in galleries that display images chronologically.

I have hundreds/thousands of images on my tablet (organized in folders), especially older ones I want to edit. It'll take forever to find within these apps galleries.

One thing I noticed is that downloaded images appear at the top of these galleries. So I thought a workaround would be to COPY & PASTE the older image (via file managers) - so that it appears as new.

But for some reason, Android will only treat downloaded images as new - not copied pasted images.

Is there any trick to make this work? Because I'm forced to edit on Android - but it's so annoying to do simple things as in Windows.

Comment: timestamp is prefered before mtime. usually a picture's timestamp is saved in metadata or EXIF data of image. this timestamp is never changed no matter how often you copy a file. however, if timestamp is missing, the linux mtime (which exist for any file) is used instead (fail-safe). mtime is changed for each copy of a file.

Comment: If the image is a photo taken using camera (app or device), it most probably contains Date Taken as EXIF metadata as alecxs mentioned. In this case if your gallery app prioritise Date Taken, you need to remove metadata of the image. Secondly you need to make sure that the app you are using for copying doesn't retain the original Modified Data of the image. Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215582/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209243/218526